# jquery move map marker mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, maps

OK iv been struggling with this for almost a week now and no matter what i try i cant seem to get this working.

I have successfully managed to run a timer (setInterval) to retrieve values from a mysql table, this file is call apijson.php and return them to the string and its fine. (Goes to Output div)

Im running into problems integrating it into google map api to move and pan the marker to the coordinated just retrieved.

I hope i make sense in what im trying to achieve.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.953429,-3.188095);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Marker'
  });

  moveBus( map, marker );
}

function moveBus( map, marker ) {

    marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( 0, 0 ) );
    map.panTo( new google.maps.LatLng( 0, 0 ) );

};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <div id="output"></div>

  <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function() 
  {

    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'apijson.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "Driver=<?php echo $_GET['Driver']; ?>",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var xx = data[7];              //latitude
        var xy = data[8];           //longtude
        var drv = data[2];           //driver
        var clsn = data[1];           //id
        marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( data[7], data[8] ) );
    map.panTo( new google.maps.LatLng( data[7], data[8] ) );

        $('#output').html("<b>Lat : </b>"+xx+"<b> Long : </b>"+xy+"<b> Driver : </b>"+drv+" ("+clsn+")");     //Set output element html

      } 
    }, 5000);

  }); 


  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set local vars, i.e. `marker`, inside your function `initialize` which you try to access within your ajax `success` event. If it was global, say, `window.myTestMarker = /* .... */;` and you'd then access it using `window.myTestMarker` from within the `success` event, you should get closer to your desired result.

Comment: Really sorry, im just starting out with ajax/javascript. How would i put this into my code, iv tried changing al my vars to window.varname and now i get a blank page. im pulling my hair out. lol. many thanks for help.